# Why wont my program identify prime numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using the Sieve of Erastosthenes method in order to make a program that prints all the prime numbers up to 1000. The program is running but for some reason the program will not remove the numbers that are composite. Since my program runs I am certain it is just a logic error and that the error is somewhere in my identifyPrimes function but I have been unable to locate it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

void initializeNumbers ( char number[], int ARRAY_SIZE )
{
    number[0]  =  'I' ; // 'I' means Ignore
    number[1]  =  'I' ;

    for ( int i = 2 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i ++ )
        number[i]  =  'U' ;

    /*  --------------------------------------------------------
        Function indexOfLeastU returns the least index such that
        the character stored at that index is 'U', with the
        exception that -1 is returned if no array element has
        value 'U'.
        -------------------------------------------------------- */
    int indexOfLeastU ( char number[], int ARRAY_SIZE )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i ++ )
            if ( number[i] == 'U' )
                return  i ;

        return  -1 ;
    } // end indexOfLeastU function

    /*  --------------------------------------------------------
        Function identifyPrimes identifies which numbers are
        prime by placing 'P's at those indices.
        Composite #'s are marked with 'C's.
        -------------------------------------------------------- */
    void  identifyPrimes ( char number[], int ARRAY_SIZE )
    {
        int  leastU  =  indexOfLeastU ( number, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;
        while ( leastU >= 0 )
            {
                number [leastU]  =  'P' ; // 'P' for Prime

                // mark multiples as Composite ...
                for ( int i = (2 * leastU) ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i += leastU)

                    number [leastU]  =  'C' ; // 'C' for Composite
                leastU  =  indexOfLeastU ( number, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;

            } // end while loop
    } // end identifyPrimes function

    /*  --------------------------------------------------------
        Function printPrimes prints those array indices whose
        corresponding elements have the value 'P'.
        -------------------------------------------------------- */
    void printPrimes ( char number[], int ARRAY_SIZE )
    {
        // print the indices at which a 'P' is stored ...
        cout << "\nThe prime numbers up to 1000 are:\n\n" ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i ++ )
            if ( number[i] == 'P' )
                cout << i << '\t' ;
        cout << endl << endl ;
    } // end printPrimes function

    int main ( )
    {
        // declare & initialize constants ...
        const int  MAX_NUMBER  =  1000 ;
        const int  ARRAY_SIZE  =  MAX_NUMBER + 1 ;

        // declare array ...
        char  number [ ARRAY_SIZE ]  =  { '\0' } ;

        initializeNumbers ( number, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;

        identifyPrimes ( number, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;

        printPrimes ( number, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;
        system("pause");
    } // end main function
```

Comment: Your braces aren't balanced, there's no close of the `initializeNumbers()` function.

Comment: You should get in the habit of _always_ putting `{...}` around the bodies of `if`, `while`, `for`, etc. even if there's just a single statement in the body.

Comment: That is a very complicated code for implementing the sieve. The algorithm is very simple, and I can barely understand your code. You could print whole table on the output that would probably help find error.

Comment: what is your output? or just loops forever?

Comment: I added a brace to my code, but the brace dosn't change the way my program ran, and the program still dosn't solve my issue with identifying prime numbers.

Comment: The output is 501 to 1000, it just couts from 501 to 1000. The loop does end and the program will close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    // mark multiples as Composite ...
    for ( int i = (2 * leastU) ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i += leastU)

        number [leastU]  =  'C' ; // 'C' for Composite
```

The assignment should be:

```
        number[i] = 'C';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in here.

```
for ( int i = (2 * leastU) ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i += leastU)
    number [leastU]  =  'C'
```

It should be

```
number[i] = 'C';
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, instead of the ignor sign,  you should implement this with linked-list (you can use std::list). then you can just delete the elements you now specify to be ignored.

This program (at least as shown here) won't compile since you forgot closing parenthesis for `initializeNumbers`.

next, you need to fix this loop:

```
for ( int i = (2 * leastU) ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; i += leastU)

                number [leastU]  =  'C' ; // 'C' for Composite
```

You need to use `i` instead of `leastU`